# Determining how to pick a record after grouping. (Rails 3.0)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been using a scope that allows for the retrieval of the record with the highest id in a given group. I recently changed the way records are added to the database so that the record with the highest id is not necessarily the record with the most recent data; that would be the record with the highest :end_time.

```
scope :latest_record_in_group, unique.select('max(id) as id')
```

where unique is as follows:

```
scope :unique, group(:field_1, :field_2, :field_3, :field_4)
```

Now what I need is to select the id of the record with the highest :end_time and I'm baffled. It seems that I can't alter how activeRecord decides which of the records in a group gets selected as the representative of said group. As it stands, it seems to be the record with the highest :id by default. Any insight as to how I can select the record with the highest :end_time would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: disambiguation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you should use

case you're using `rails 3`

```
Model.find(:all, :order => "end_time")
```

case you're using `rails4`

```
Model.order(:end_time).all
```

Comment: I need to group first (using the :unique scope) and return the :id of the record with the highest :end_time of each group. My problem is, I see no way of telling the group routine to keep the record with the highest end_time (for each group; this is the key. it needs to be for each group) rather than the record with the highest id.

Comment: @TheCulprit in maths, we say that standard ordering ≤ of the natural numbers provides a well ordered set ;) If you get the maximum of the whole groups, then why bothering having the max for each sets. I think I didn't understand what you are trying to fetch

Comment: I work for test automation in the product verification/quality control department of a network switch manufacturing company. we test the hardware. Our automated tests run multiple time. I will be less abstract in my question so that you might understand the problem. (see next comment)

Comment: our hardware is called a platform in the database. A platform has port_types. A test_script runs using this hardware and a test can have options specified by a test_prefix. I use a rails app to report on the outcome of these tests. Multiple test runs can occur for a given software build. I need the latest result for each configuration. a configuration is determined by grouping (:prefix, :port_type, :platform, :script). grouping all of the results for a software build using the unique scope described above yields one record for each configuration. (see next comment)

Comment: That record is the test run with the highest id. This query should return one record for each distinct grouping (multiple records). I cannot find a way the specify how activeRecord determines which record in a given group to return. As it is, I am getting the records from each group with the highest id. I want the records form each group with the highest end_time.